# Why is my Discord Bot is not responding when I mention it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hi I am making it so when I ping the bot exactly it message something but when I do "@Wide#9236" It does not respond with anything. It worked a week ago but now it does not work suddenly.

I am using Discord.JS v12.5.1

Here is my code:

```
bot.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === "dm") return
    
    if (message.content == bot.user.toString()) { 

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Prefix")
        .setDescription('My Prefix is "!"')
        .setFooter('Type !help for more information')
        .setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        message.channel.send(embed)
  
   }
  
  })
```

And I have no idea how to fix it as it worked a week ago.

Comment: I believe the `toString()` introduces a zero width space. You can look into `message.mentions`

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if the bot was mentionned with `message.mentions`

```
if (message.mentions.has(client.user)) {
    if (message.mentions.everyone) return;
    // your stuff
}
```